# Understanding calling one function inside another C

Tags: c, function, recursion, primes, stdio

I'd like to ask the following misunderstandings of C language, which I see I'm having.

I'm sorry if the code is not properly indented, I tried as much as I could but there are not so many guides on the internet.

The program asked given a starting number 'val' and a Even-Odd or Odd-Even alternating sequence (which stops whenever this rules is violated) to print the greater prime number with 'val'.

I tried with two functions and the main: one to control the GCD between two given numbers and the other to keep tracks of the greatest one, but I think I miss something in the code or in the conception of C function,

Because when compiled it returns me 0 or great number which I'm not entering.

One example to understand what I should do:

If my sequence was 10, 7, 8, 23 and my val was 3, I had to print 23, because it is the greatest integer prime with 3.

Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mcd(int a, int b)
{   // Gcd function
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    else
        return mcd(b % a, b);
}

int valuta(int val, int h)  // Valuing Max function
{
    int temp = 0;
    if (mcd(val, h) == 1 && h > temp)
        temp = h;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    int val, d, x, y, z, t, contatore = 1;
    scanf("%d", &val);
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    if (x > y && mcd(val, x) == 1)
    {   // Two options
        t = x;
    }
    else if (y > x && mcd(val, y) == 1)
    {
        t = y;
    }
    if ((x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0) || (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 1))
    {   // Bad case
        if (x > y && mcd(val, x) == 1)
        {
            t = x;
            contatore = 0;
        }
        else if (y > x && mcd(val, y) == 1)
        {
            t = y;
            contatore = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (contatore == 1)
        {
            scanf("%d", &z);
            t = valuta(val, z);
            if (x % 2 == 0 && z % 2 == 0)
            {   // Even- Odd - Even
                scanf("%d", &d);
                t = valuta(val, d);
                if (d % 2 == 0)
                {
                    contatore = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    contatore = 0;
                }
            }
            if (x % 2 == 1 && z % 2 == 1)
            {   //Odd- Even- Odd
                scanf("%d", &d);
                t = valuta(val, d);
                if (d % 2 == 1)
                {
                    contatore = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    contatore = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

PS.  Is there any way to reduce the number of lines of code or to reduce the effort in coding?  I mean, a straightforward solution will be helpful.

Comment: Your function `valuta` is flawed, as each time it is called the variable `temp` will *always* be zero.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your indentation is not very good, and your curly-brace positioning is very unusual and won't be able to follow indentation (having the closing `}` follow the indentation generally makes it easier to read and see when a block ends).

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere!?  I suggest that reduce the question to 1) What you intended to happen, 2) What actually happens.  Instead you have made some wild assumption that the problem (whatever it is) is related to some misunderstanding about function calls.  In general it is better not to try to suggest what the problem is.  Here the only reasonable answer to the implied question is that your function calls and definitions are entirely valid and that you have no problem with that.  That does not really resolve your problem however does it?

Comment: Your code accepts user input - it would help if you included some example input, the expected result and the actual result.   The input does not prompt, it is unclear what values are to be input when.  Your description of the purpose of this code is entirely unclear.

Comment: What for example does _"greatest integer prime with 3"_ mean?

Comment: You have two if/else constructs with the condition `(d % 2 == 0)` where both the if and else blocks are identical - `contatore = 0;` - as such the if/else is entirely redundant because `contatore` is always assigned zero, and only 40 values are ever accepted.

Comment: There is no doubt a simple way of accepting an alternating odd/even or even/odd sequence but you need to ask about that separately - your current implementation is overcomplex and does not work.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you,you have been very clear, trying to fix it, thanks.

Comment: The logic in `valuta()` looks wrong, when you test `h > temp`, `temp` is always zero.  It is not the concept of functions that you have trouble with, it is a coding logic issue I think.

Comment: Advice: test and validate the functions `mcd()` and then `valuta()` on their own with a much simpler test framework using a range of hard coded test values for which you know the correct result, before using them in more complex code such as this.  That way when it does not work, you will be reasonably confident that it is the calling code rather then these functions at fault.  Learn to use a debugger too, so you can exercise the code step-by-step, and inspect the variable values directly as the code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `valuta()` function is flawed in that it needs to return the maximum qualifying value so far but has no knowledge of the previous maximum - `temp` is always zero.  The following takes the previous maximum as an argument:

```
int valuta(int val, int h, int previous )
{
    return ( mcd(val, h) == 1 && h > previous ) ? h : previous ;
}
```

And is called from `main()` thus:

```
t = valuta( val, x, t ) ;
```

The test `mcd(val, h) == 1` is flawed, because `mcd()` only ever returns the value of parameter `b` which is not modified in the recursion, so will never return 1, unless the argument `b` is 1.  Since I have no real idea what `mcd()` is intended to do, I cannot tell you how to fix it. It appear to be a broken implementation of Euclid's greatest common divisor algorithm, which correctly implemented would be:

```
int mcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return mcd(b, a % b);
}
```

But I cannot see how that relates to:

> "[...] he greatest integer prime with 3 [...]

The odd/even even/odd sequence handling can be drastically simplified to the extent that it is shorter and simpler than your method (as requested) - and so that it works!

The following is a clearer starting point, but may not be a solution since it is unclear what it is it is supposed to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int mcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return mcd(b, a % b);
}

int valuta(int val, int h, int previous )
{
    return ( mcd(val, h) && h > previous ) ? h : previous ;
}

int main()
{
    int val, x, t ;
    printf( "Enter value:") ;
    scanf("%d", &val);

    typedef enum 
    {
        EVEN = 0,
        ODD = 1,
        UNDEFINED
    } eOddEven ;

    eOddEven expect = UNDEFINED ;
    bool sequence_valid = true ;

    printf( "Enter sequence in odd/even or even/odd order (break sequence to exit):\n") ;
    while( sequence_valid )
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if( expect == UNDEFINED )
        {
            // Sequence order determined by first value
            expect = (x & 1) == 0 ? EVEN : ODD ;
        }
        else
        {
            // Switch expected odd/even
            expect = (expect == ODD) ? EVEN : ODD ;

            // Is new value in the expected sequence?
            sequence_valid = (expect == ((x & 1) == 0 ? EVEN : ODD)) ;
        }

        //  If the sequence is valid...
        if( sequence_valid )
        {
           // Test if input is largest qualifying value
           t = valuta( val, x, t ) ;
        }
    }

    // Result
    printf("Result: %d\n", t);

    return 0;
}
```